# How to avoid runtime error when running row data to column script - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get "The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly" error while running the following Google Apps Script for my actual dataset containing over a thousand rows in Google Sheets, however it runs fine for a smaller dataset

```
function RowDataToCol() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var tar = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
    
    var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    data.push(["","","",""]); // empty row
    var i = 1;
    var k = 1;
    var rows = [];
    while( data[i][0] !== "" ) {
      k = 1;
      while( data[i][k] !== "" ) {
        rows.push([data[i][0],data[0][k],data[i][k]]);
        k++;
      }
      i++;
    }
    tar.getRange(2,2,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
  }
}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: What is the precise error message?

Comment: @Cooper - 
12:06:36 PM Notice Execution started
12:07:09 PM Error The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try this

```
function funk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.clearContents();
  let a = hA.slice();
  a.shift()
  let obj = { pA: [] };
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      obj[r[0]] = a.map((e, j) => r[j + 1])
      obj.pA.push(r[0])
    }
  })
  let oA = [];
  obj.pA.forEach((p, i) => {
    obj[p].forEach((e, j) => { 
      oA.push([p,a[j],e])
    })
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oA));
  osh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}

Execution log
12:22:13 PM Notice  Execution started
12:22:14 PM Info    [["A","Area1","RU"],["A","Area2","RU"],["A","Area3","RU"],["B","Area1","SU"],["B","Area2","RU"],["B","Area3","UR"],["C","Area1","UR"],["C","Area2","UR"],["C","Area3","UR"]]
12:22:14 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Input:

| Name | Area1 | Area2 | Area3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | RU | RU | RU |
| B | SU | RU | UR |
| C | UR | UR | UR |

Output:

| A | Area1 | RU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Area2 | RU |
| A | Area3 | RU |
| B | Area1 | SU |
| B | Area2 | RU |
| B | Area3 | UR |
| C | Area1 | UR |
| C | Area2 | UR |
| C | Area3 | UR |